# Can't resolve cors error in react and node app

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I have just deployed a react/express app in Heroku which initially worked for a couple of minutes but then the dreaded cors error came up which I can never seem to fix. I've tried everything else suggested on other posts but nothing seems to work for me.

I've tried adding a proxy in my react app with:

```
 "proxy": "http://127.0.0.1:4000", (and also trying) ->
 "proxy": "http://localhost:4000",
```

This didn't work so I tried adding the cors package in node which didn't work either. This is driving me crazy and I don't know what else I can try.

```
const app = require("./app");
const cors = require("cors");

app.use(
  cors({
    allowedHeaders: ["authorization", "Content-Type"], // you can change the headers
    exposedHeaders: ["authorization"], // you can change the headers
    origin: "*",
    methods: "GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE",
    preflightContinue: false
  });
);
const port = process.env.PORT || 4000;

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Listening on ${port}`);
});
```

I'm using axios for requests for example:

```
const allMoviesData = await axios.get("/movies?limit=12");
```

In chrome I get:

```
GET http://localhost:4000/movies?limit=12 net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
(anonymous) @ bundle.js:31
bundle.js:31 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Network Error
    at e.exports (bundle.js:31)
    at XMLHttpRequest.d.onerror (bundle.js:31)
```

In firefox I get:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:4000/movies?limit=12&searchBy=genres&filter=adventure.

Uncaught (in promise) Error: Network Error
    exports http://localhost:3000/bundle.js:31
    onerror http://localhost:3000/bundle.js:31

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:4000/movies?limit=12. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).
```

Any other suggestions would be appreciated.
[image]

Comment: when the app is deployed to heroku does the url change ie instead of the request coming from heroku is it coming from the url (or ip:port) of the deployed machine?

does the heroku deployment host both the express server and the react client ?

Comment: so ive just noticed that when I run the app locally and then go to the deployed app the cors error goes away and i am getting the data. If I stop the local server though the deployed app then gets the cors error again and I cant get the data. It does work locally but it must be how heroku is deploying the app or possibly how its setup in my app.

Comment: Errm... Probably not your problem, but that extra semicolon after your ``cors`` function call should not be there.

Answer (score 0):

Check the request and response headers.

The bluish parts should be the same.

[image]

If they are not the same for you, that means whatever you are doing, isn't working like it should be.

Comment: I've added the same image above for what I get